Adding records to related models in a RestAPI
I want to insert data in a json body that store some related records. Let´s say that i have this structure of table: "ferramentas":
{
"title": "hotel",
"link": "https://github.com/typicode/hotel",
"description": "Local app manager. Start apps within your browser, developer tool with local .localhost domain and https out of the box.",
"tags":\["node", "organizing", "webapps", "domain", "developer", "https", "proxy"\]
}

where 'tags' are a related model. the relationships is many to many betwen the two models. There´s a way to insert this in a body requisition using some toll like insomnia? or give just a link of the documentation or wether tutorial on the internet that explain this?
Bellow my store function
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title'=>'required|string|max:255',
            'link'=> 'required|url|max:255',
            'description' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'tag'=> 'required|array',
            'tag.name' => 'required|max:255'
        ]);

        $ferramentas = Ferramentas::create($request->only(['title', 'link', 'description']));

        $tags = [];

        foreach($request->input('tag') as $tagName){
            $tag = Tags::firstOrCreate(['name'=>$tagName])->id();
        }

        $ferramentas->tags()->sync($tags);

        return  FerramentasResource::collection($ferramentas);



    }

My models :
\\ Tags
class Tags extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable= [
        'id',
        'name'
    ];

    protected $table = 'tags';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function ferramentas(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tags::class, 'ferramentas_tags', 'tag_id', 'ferramenta_id');
    }

}

\\ Ferramentas

class Ferramentas extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'title',
        'descriptions',
        'link',
        'tags'
    ];

    protected $table = 'ferramentas';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function tags(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tags::class, 'ferramentas_tags', 'ferramenta_id', 'tag_id' );
    }

}

My Routes:

Route::get('ferramentas', [FerramentasController::class, 'index']);    
Route::get('ferramentas/api/{tag}', [FerramentasController::class, 'show']);    
Route::post('ferramentas/api', [FerramentasController::class, 'store']);

I just read some tutorials and search in the documentation of laravel, but dont fint nothing that could healp me - i´m a bad research.
For now, when i send a http Post in insomnia with, for example, this json
{
"title": "hotel",
"link": "https://github.com/typicode/hotel",
"description": "Local app manager. Start apps within your browser, developer tool with local .localhost domain and https out of the box.",
"tags":\["node", "organizing", "webapps", "domain", "developer", "https", "proxy"\]
}

nothing happend in the database. any records are added to my tables.

Check and show the url  through which you access store(Request $request) method.Most likely you are accessing this api/ferramentas route that is why you are getting error.

i edit the post. now nothin are happening on my db

Which url you were accessing when you are getting this error The POST method is not supported for route api/ferramentas. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. ? share that URL .

Your problem might be that you pass the key "tags"
but in your controller, the store()function, expects a key tag not tags, so try to be consistent in the naming convention(use same keys in the controller and when making the request)
Also it would be best if you renamed the Tags model to Tag(single)
As you can see, you want to upload many Tag objects, since you have the foreach, but your validation expects only 1 object of tag, in that case, you should do it like this:
tags.* => string, to ensure that each element of the array will be a string
 $request->validate([
                'title'=>'required|string|max:255',
                'link'=> 'required|url|max:255',
                'description' => 'required|string|max:255',
                'tags'=> 'required|array',
                'tags.*' => 'required|string'
            ]);
    
        $tags = collect();
    
foreach($request->tags as $tag){
    $tags->push(new \App\Models\Tag(
    ['name'=>$tag]
    ))}
    \App\Models\Tag::upsert($tags->toArray(), ['id']);

In this case, you insert many Tags in a single database transaction.
